# HTTPS call not referring the correct SSL certificate for the corresponding site

Tags: apache, ssl, https, coldfusion

I'm having two coldfusion applications which runs on Apache web server

> https://site1.com
>
> https://site2.com

Both having its own SSL certificate and are configured in `httpd-ssl.conf` file with Name based virtual host for each site.

When I'm doing a HTTPS call from Site1.com to Site2.com,

```
    httpService = new http(); 
    httpService.setMethod("get");
    httpService.setUrl("https://site2.com/comp.cfc?method=amethod&ID=12");
    result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
```

it gives the following error

`I/O Exception: hostname in certificate didn't match: <site2.com> != <site1.com>`

Actually it should use site2's SSL certificate. But not sure why it is using Site1's SSL certificate and giving the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a Server Name Indication (SNI) issue. SNI is a TLS extension allowing to host several HTTPS servers on the same server.

You can confirm this issue using:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect site2.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject
```

If you see something like `CN=site1.com` try this:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect site2.com:443 -servername site2.com | openssl x509 -noout -subject
```

if you get `CN=site2.com`, this is a SNI issue.

You can look at this [bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3598342), more specifically this comment:

> The SNI support has been added in ColdFusion 11. The change required for supporting this is quite big and therefore it can't be backported to ColdFusion 10.

Other workarounds could be to host your 2 HTTPS sites on **2 separate servers**, to set up a **unique SSL certificate valid for both names** (using X509 SubjectAltName extension) or to **disable certificate CN validation** (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm checking your suggestion in my machine, So while I use "echo "" | openssl s_client -connect site2.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject" This gives the CN=site1.com. But when I use "echo "" | openssl s_client -connect site2.com:443 -servername site2.com | openssl x509 -noout -subject" I got unknown option -servername

Comment: Well I think your openssl is not up to date. Did you try to access your sites using a browser? Does it work?

Comment: yup! In browser, both the sites are working with correct SSL certificates.

Comment: Could you try to update your OpenSSL and re-run the second command line please?
However as it works fine with browser, it almost proves this is a SNI issue.

Comment: Yes Jyo!  It is an SNI issue. But I've solved this issue by creating single SSL certificate, which support multiple domains. :)

Comment: That's another workaround! Thank you, I will edit my answer considering your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the SSL certificate into ColdFusion/Java keystore. If this doesn't help, add -Djavax.net.debug=all in jvm.config for ColdFusion. This would require a CF service restart. Then try the SSL call.

Comment: I've imported both site's SSL certificates into coldfusion